# Trasform SQL Cursor using Pyspark in Databricks

Tags: loops, pyspark, cursor, databricks, rdd

We have a cursor in DB2 which reads in each loop data from 2 tables. At the end of each loop, after inserting the data to a target table, we update records related to each loop in these 2 tables before moving to the next loop. An indicative example is the below:

```
FETCH CUR1 INTO V_A1, V_A2, V_C1, V_C3, V_M1, V_M2

SELECT V_M1
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE A1=V_A1

SELECT V_M2
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE C1=V_C1

IF ..... THEN V_B1 = V_M1-V_M2 ELSE ....


INSERT INTO TARGET
...
VALUES
(V_A1, V_A2, ...)

UPDATE TABLE_1
SET V_M1 = V_M1 - V_B1


UPDATE TABLE_2
SET V_M2 = V_M2 - V_B1


FETCH CUR1 INTO V_A1, V_A2, V_C1, V_C3, V_M1, V_M2

END WHILE

CLOSE CUR1
```

Just to note that A1, C1 are not unique across the data.

Could you please suggest a way to transform it using Pyspark? Performance also matters as we speak about a large amount of data. I saw that RDDs are immutable in case we were trying RDD-map option.

Comment: You are right - We have more than 500k rows. I mentioned it in order to exclude pandas as I read that it is indicated for <1000 rows

Comment: Can you describe what you need to do in terms of actual execution?